# What's the right way to integrate Grunt into a Spring/Gradle build?

Tags: javascript, spring, gradle, gruntjs

I have a Spring Boot project that is built with Gradle. All my front-end code lives under `src/main/resources/static`. This also includes my `bower_components`, `node_modules` (for Grunt tasks), etc.

Right now, I have my main Gradle build script exec the Grunt build, which concatenates/minifies all my JavaScript, and they go under `src/main/resources/static/dist`. Then, when `processResources` gets executed in Gradle, the entire `src/main/resources/static/dist` gets copied to the build directory. This doesn't seem right to me - the only stuff that should end up in the build directory are the concatenated/minified JS, CSS, HTML and images.

I've searched high and low but haven't found any clear direction here. Is there a best practice for building a project in this way?

Comment: This seems like a good setup. Would you share your gradle and bower configuration?

Comment: I've actually changed my setup completely from last year. I'm using Gulp now, and everything goes into my build directory - not in src. If you're still curious about my setup, you can see the project here: https://github.com/joeattardi/tailstreamer/tree/develop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files generated as part of the build shouldn't go into `src`, but somewhere under the `build` directory (say `build/grunt`). What's left is to include them in archives as necessary. For example:

```
war.dependsOn(grunt)
war {
    from "build/grunt"
}
```

Or, if the Grunt task declares it outputs:

```
war {
    from grunt
}
```

Comment: and if you need to place the static files in a specific dir in the WAR, you can add "into": `from "build/grunt" { into "some/dir" }`